# Windows 10 - poor initial connect time with no internet access

Tags: networking, windows-10

I've got a Windows 10 system sitting on an isolated network with a CentOS 6 box that has a samba share (it's a demo setup for our product). When I say isolated, I mean it - no internet connection!

I'm using fixed IPs to connect between the systems. So to open the CentOS box's share on the Win 10 system, you'd type '\\192.168.0.223\Archive' into a file explorer window on Windows 10. Credentials are saved, but it takes anywhere from 20-45 seconds to connect and show the contents of the share. After that, it's fine.

The infuriating thing is that if I plug these systems into my local network (the static IPs are valid there), they work perfectly. It's almost like having an internet connection makes everything OK for some reason.

I've tried a number of things:

1. Putting a DHCP server on the isolated network - no change.
2. Disabling Windows Defender - no change.
3. Added a name for the CentOS box to the hosts file on the Win 10 box - no change
4. Disabled Smartscreen of apps and files - no change
5. Added Windows Defender exclusion for the CentOS box - no change
6. Added hosts file on CentOS box with Laptop's name/ip - no change.
7. Added lmhosts file on CentOS box with Laptop's name/ip - no change.

I'm getting really annoyed here because I can't even figure out which piece of gear is fouling everything up. And as you can see by the fact that I'm playing with name service files while using IPs, I'm out of sensible ideas.

Any clues greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this boiled down to me being stupid.

The CentOS box was configured with a name server which didn't exist when the network was isolated.

Some wireshark tracing of the connection attempts showed that it was performing DNS lookups (on it's own name) in the 'fast' case, and just waiting in the 'slow' case.

Removing the DNS server address from the system on the isolated network made the whole problem vanish.